# Timers in Abstract Gui API

Tags: c++, user-interface

Here is the basic idea of what I want to do:

Each widget, when part of the Gui has access to the event manager. The event manager is polymorphic so it contains functions from the underlying graphics / timer api. What I want to do is, allow Widgets to register timers, where they would call a function which would internally call the event manager to register the timer. Here is the problem, when a widget is first created, it is not part of the Gui. Therefore, no one could ever register timers in the widget constructor.

I thought of the fact that I could queue requests and when the widget becomes part of a gui, and can access the event manager, it can then dequeue the requests, but the problem with this is that it doesn't really allow me to do something like:

```
Timer *timer = registerTimer(0.17);

if(timer == NULL)
{
   //uh ohs
}
else
{
   timer->start();
}
```

Are there maybe better ways around my problem?

Thanks

Comment: For future reference, "GUI" is usually either written in all-caps or no-caps.  Just a little thing that bugged me.  ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Event management and providing timing facilities are 2 very different functionalities, so I would try to decouple event manager into 2 separate classes. Then you could make `TimerManager` a singleton and register timers from any places you like.

Alternatively if you cannot decouple event manager class as it is now, you can try to make it a singleton and access timing facilities this way.

Comment: I did think about this, only thing is I don't like singletons in OOP :(

Comment: Hm, I see. Though it seems natural to use them sometimes. For instance it should be perfectly legal to register timer in widget ctor and how to achieve that without passing `TimerManager` as parameter?